# What’s the most energetic particles that can theoretically reach the earth?

Tags: particle-physics, estimation, neutrinos, cosmic-rays

In recent years several ultra high energy cosmic ray events are observed on Earth. These particles carry energies way beyond even the most powerful particle accelerators we can realistically build. They are likely created from extremely high energy particle collisions near black holes or neutron stars. However, not all ultra high energy particles can survive the long journey to the earth. For example, once the energy of gamma ray photons exceeds a threshold of about 80 TeV (if I recall correctly), they will annihilate with the CMB photons to create electron-positron pairs. The energy of charged particles like protons are also limited by the [GZK limit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit) again due to scattering with the CMB.

However, there are several more weakly interacting particles. For example, neutrinos only have weak interaction (if not counting gravity) which makes scattering extremely unlikely. Does that mean the energy limit of cosmic neutrinos is even higher (comparable to GUT or even the Planck scale)? Detection of ultra high energy cosmic rays may provide an alternative way to study physics under extreme energy scales. For example, many GUT models predict the existence of magnetic monopoles. If we can detect cosmic neutrinos at the GUT scales but no magnetic monopoles, we may be able to rule out the existence of monopoles.

Comment: How far is the source? If it's close, some very high energy stuff could make it to "us". The problem about neutrinos is that there just aren't that many high luminosity sources. I thought the neutrino astronomy stuff is slowly petering out because there is nothing bright in the sky.

Comment: Depending on whether they come from out Milky Way or more distant galaxies. The distances of gamma ray bursts may be a good reference point.

Comment: Neutrinos are mostly detected as “stray bullets”. But even detection of high energy stray neutrinos can indicate the existence of high energy collisions in the universe.

Comment: *Does that mean the energy limit of cosmic neutrinos is even higher (comparable to GUT or even the Planck scale)?* Have you read the wikipedia article you linked? Seems to me that this question is directly answered there, no?